# PyDev - Unresolved Relative Import - weird fix?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, python-import, importerror

I have the following directory structure:

```
root/
    - project/
        - dir1/
            - subdir1/
                - subdir2/
                    - __init__.py
                    - module1.py
        - dir2/
            - __init__.py
            - module2.py
```

and in module2, I do the following relative import:

```
from ..dir1.subdir1.subdir2 import module1
```

this works just fine - code runs well.

When my dir2 name is all characters (e.g. "testfolder"), Eclipse gives me an unresolved import error for that import line.
When my dir2 name has a dash '-' in it, Eclipse seems to be magically happy.

What's going on here?

Elaboration of my use-case:

I am using the [slash testing framework](https://slash.readthedocs.io/en/master/) where the python path seems to change to the directory of the test module currently running. So despite running module2 through slash from 'project' directory, this does not work:

```
from dir1.subdir1.subdir2 import module1
```

I have to instead navigate out using the .. in the path. Any ideas on how to equip PyDev to handle that?